# R: multiple windrose plot using windRose from openair package

Tags: r, plot

I want to compare the wind distribution between 8 months. I use the function `windRose` from the `openair` package. In the original data there´s an extra column called "month" with the name each month.

My code is:

```
library(openair)
windRose(data, ws = "ws", wd = "wd", layout=c(2,4), type = "month"....
```

By using type = "month" it automatically draws a plot for every month in a big 2 x 4 obverview-plot which is very nice to compare everything. It looks very fine, but the months are in a weird order and that´s quite annoying.

Questions:

- Does anybody know how to tell R in which order to plot the months (it should be March, April, May....)? That´s also the original order in the .csv.
- Is it possible to add a North-South-Grid to the plot?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Ben

Comment: That is strange. I made a similar plot and the months are in the right order in my case. What is the order of the factor levels of data$Month?

Answer (score 0):

YES  you need to create something like this:

viento$mes<-factor(viento$mes, levels = c("Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre",
                                "Noviembre","Diciembre","Enero","Febrero","Marzo"))

and in type you need to write type="mes"

Answer (score 0):

R assigns each factor a level. So whenever you deal with factors you need to take care of these levels.

You can specify what level of each factor you want using something like this

```
data$Month <- factor(data$Month, levels =c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")
```